# How to add margin to fixed inner container within fixed outer container?

Tags: html, css

I want to add margin (`10px`) to `.inner-container` (blue) which is `960px` fixed width which also inside `.outer-container` (`360px` fixed width).

To make it scrollable, i set `overflow: scroll` to .`outer-container`
to add margin to inner container, I set `margin: 10px;` to `.inner-container`.

the problem is there are no margin on the right side of `.inner-container`.

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #555;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container-inner {
  width: 960px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, by adding one more div (with 980px width), to wrap inner container, so applied margin will work:

```css
.outer-container {
 width:360px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #555;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.inner-wrap {
  width:980px;
}
.container-inner {
  width: 960px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  margin:10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="inner-wrap">
  <div class="container-inner"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving padding to outer container instead of giving margin to inner container.

```
.outer-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #555;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container-inner {
  width: 960px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  display:block
}
```

Comment: it is coming but because of scroll it is not visible  try increasing the padding of right to see the change

Answer (score 0):

You need one more wrap between parent and child `div` element.

Consider the following markup:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="inner-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add `padding` + `width` on this middle element:

```
.middle-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 960px;
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Demo:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.outer-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #555;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.middle-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 960px;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="inner-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```